# How to response to user events in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events

I have a code snippit like so:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(data) {
    // call some method on my controller
});
```

Is there an 'Angular' way of doing this?

The sample above was poor.  I actually want to be able to respond top the mouse up and mouse down events separately.

**Answer**

Angular has `ngMousedown` and `ngMouseup` directives..

Comment: It's not in the documentation, looks like I need to use Angular-Ui, Ui-Utils.

Comment: OK, totally overlooked `ng-click`.  Obvious now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've defined the ng-app and what not for the page,

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-click="handleData(data")></div>
```

and in the controller for the app, define

```
$scope.handleData = function(data) { ... }
```